# Unable to set custom paths for multiple APIS. (Socket.IO + ExpressJS + Nginx)

Tags: javascript, express, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to set up multiple APIs on a single VPS and serve them through Nginx.
I want to have all of them in separate sub-locations like the example below:

---

Express remote paths:

```
[myhost].com/apps/app1/api
[myhost].com/apps/app2/api
```

Express local paths:

```
localhost:[app1 port]
localhost:[app2 port]
```

---

Socket.IO remote paths:

```
[myhost].com/apps/app1/api/socket.io
[myhost].com/apps/app2/api/socket.io
```

Socket.IO local paths:

```
localhost:[app1 port]/socket.io
localhost:[app2 port]/socket.io
```

---

Express works as desired, I am able to access it locally like this:
`curl -ivL http://localhost:[app1 port]`

But, because of Socekt.IO 'path' property, Socket.IO responses only on:
`curl -ivL http://localhost:[app1 port]/apps/app1/api/socket.io/?EIO=4`

Without Socket.IO 'path' I am not able to access it remotely.

```
const ioServer = new socketIo.Server(httpServer, {
  .....
  path: "/apps/app1/api/socket.io", <---- this 'path' property
});
```

Nginx configuration:

```
  ......
  location /apps {
    index _;
    autoindex on;

    location /apps/app1/api/ {
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    Host             $http_host;
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:[app1 port];
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header    Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header    Connection       "upgrade";
    }
    location /apps/app1 {
      index index.html;
    }
    ....
```

How can I get rid off **/apps/app1/api** part on localhost Socket.IO without losing the remote access?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is simple. Just use a full URI (with a trailing slash) in proxy_pass, otherwise the value will be ignored.

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to
> the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original
> request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed
> when processing the changed URI:
>
> ```
> location /some/path/ {
>   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```

from Nginx documentation
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass